# Prove $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

How do I prove $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ with delta and epsilon?

I proved geometrically that $\sin x<x$ and thus, $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|\sin x_1 - \sin x_2|\le|\sin x_1|+|\sin x_2|<|x_1|+|x_2|$$

But this doesn't help me much finding a delta...

Thanks for any help!

P.S. I'm only at the beginning of calculus so I can't use many theorems and derivation  (because they haven't been regorously proven).

Comment: I changed $sinx_1$, etc., to $\sin x_1$.  That is standard TeX usage.

Comment: This is a particular case of (at least) two more general results. First: a periodic continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Second: a Lipschitz function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzFunction.html) is uniformly continuous. To prove that $\sin$ is Lipschitz, you can use a trigonometric identity like Nameless did in his answer, or you can claim that its derivative is bounded by $1$.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. We want
$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|\sin x-\sin y\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$
Because 
$$\left|2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$
it suffices
$$2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|<\epsilon$$
when
$$\left|x-y\right|<\delta\implies \left|\frac{x-y}2\right|<\delta$$
SInce $\left|\sin x\right|\le \left|x\right|$,
$$2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\frac{x-y}2\right|<2\delta$$

Choosing $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$ will do the trick. Because $\delta$ doesn't depend on $x,y$, the continuity is uniform

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response! Why $$\left|2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$ is correct?

Also, I know how to prove $sinx<x$, but how do I show $|sinx|<|x|$? Thanks for the reply again!

Comment: because $\cos \alpha \leqslant 1 $, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Because $\left|\cos(\bullet)\right|\le 1$.

Comment: Oh, right! And why $|sinx|<|x|$?

Comment: Hi, can anyone hint me on that one?

Comment: @Harold $\sin x$ is odd

Comment: Sorry for being petty, but then sin(-x)<-x and since $sinx=sin(-x)$, and $sinx<-x$ and $sinx<x$ - how that shows $|sinx|<|x|$ => $-x<sinx<x$?

Comment: @Harold You want $\left|\sin y\right|\le \left|y\right|\iff -\sin y\le -y\iff \sin y\ge y$ for $y<0$ near $0$. But $\sin x\le x$ for $x>0$. Multipliying by $-1$ gives $-\sin x\ge -x\iff \sin (-x)\ge -x\iff \sin y\ge y$

Comment: Hi, how did you get the double angle formula from |sin(x)-sin(y)| ?

Answer (score 24):

By Mean Value Theorem,

$$ |\sin{x}- \sin{y}| \leq |x-y| |\cos{\xi}| \leq |x-y|, \quad x\leq\xi \leq y.$$

Hence, you may choose $\epsilon=\delta$.

Comment: This is a circular reasoning. For MVT you need that sine is differentiable. Since each differentiable function is continuous, you have used what you are proving.

Comment: @wdacda How is that circular reasoning?

Comment: How is that circular? I can't see it.

Answer (score 17):

Since $\sin x$ is a periodic continuous function with a period $2\pi$, it suffices to prove that it is uniformly continuous on $[0, 2\pi]$. Since $[0, 2\pi]$ is compact, this follows from the well-known theorem.

Answer (score 4):

There is an elementary geometric way to do this.  Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers; for now, assume $x, y\in(-\pi, \pi]$.  Start off at $(1,0)$ and march off signed distance $x$ to get to point $a$ and $y$ to get to point $b$ on the unit circle.  Then $|x - y|$ is the distance from $a$ to $b$ along the unit circle.  $|\sin(x) - \sin(y)|$ is the distance between the $y$-coordiates of $a$ and $b$.  Hence, in this case
$$|\sin(x) - \sin(y) | \le |x - y|.$$

This gives us uniform continuity on $(-\pi, \pi]$, so by periodciity the sine function is uniformly continuous on the entire line.

Comment: Another way to prove this identity: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620305/how-to-prove-sinx-siny-le-x-y

Comment: This answer deliberately does not appeal to the MVT; it uses purely geometric properties of the sine and cosine functions.

Comment: Yeah I know. But for a test I'm not sure if your approach would be rigorous enough. No offense.

Comment: What is not rigorous about the fact that, given a line and a point, the shortest distance between them is achieved along the perpendicular dropped from the point to the line?  In fact, this solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: Real-valued differentiable function on R with bounded derivative is uniformly continuous.

So $f'(x) = cosx$ and $|cosx| \leq 1$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous.