# Why this way of showing that $\sin x$ isn't uniformly continuous is wrong?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I know $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous and it was asked before ([Prove $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268758/prove-sin-x-is-uniformly-continuous-on-mathbb-r)). My question is related to this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/219463/105885.

Uniform continuity of $\sin x$, if we'll take $x=\pi x +\frac {\pi} 2$ and $y=\pi x$, then $|x-y|={\pi \over 2}$ but similaly to the linked answer: $|f(x)-f(y)| = |1|\ge\epsilon = 1$.

**Edit:** **With an arbitrarily small delta**: $x=\pi n +\frac 1 n, \ y=\pi n$ then $|x-y|=\frac 1 n$ So delta can be arbitrarily small, $|f(x)−f(y)|=|\sin(\frac 1 n)|$ which for an infinite amount of $n$ can be $|\sin(\frac 1 n)|≥\frac 1 2$ (Since the function furiously alternate between $1$ and $-1$ as $n\to 0$).

Why this is wrong in showing that $\sin x$ isn't uniformly continuous?

Comment: $\sin(\frac1n) < 1$ for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I can't find a specific value but you can see the graph of $sin(\frac 1 n)$ jumps from from 1 to -1, and alright, Suppose it's true, then make it $|\sin(\frac1n)| > 0.5$ for infinite amount of $n$.

Comment: Huh? $\sin(\frac1n)$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Are you confusing this with the graph of $\sin(\frac1x)$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez That's ignoring the infinite amount of $n$ where $|\sin(\frac1n)| > 0.5$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez yes, I meant as $x\to 0$.

Comment: But as $n \to 0$, $|x-y| = \frac 1n$ is not getting arbitrarily small.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Right... Well thanks for the help.

Comment: @GinKin Thanks for asking this question, it really helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $|x-y|=\pi/2$ is not arbitrarily small.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? Why does it matter if $\delta$ is arbitrarily small ?

Comment: A function $f(x)$ is NOT uniformly continuous if, for some fixed $\epsilon>0$ and for ARBITRARILY SMALL $\delta$ there exist $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$. Your $x$ and $y$ satisfy the second condition but not the first: $|x-y|=\pi/2$ and you cannot make it smaller.

Comment: Ok. What if in my example $x=\pi n +\frac 1 n$, then $|x-y|=\frac 1 n$ So delta can be arbitrarily small, $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\sin(\frac 1 n)|$ which for some $n$ can be $|\sin(\frac 1 n)|\ge 1$

Comment: $\sin\frac1n<\frac1n$ so it cannot be $\ge1$ for large $n$.