# Convergent series of a functional series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Is there any way to prove that the functional series $$g(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\,n\,a\sin(n\,c\,t)$$ is uniform convergent, given $$b_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\,\sin(nx)dx$$ $f\in \mathcal{C}^2$, $a,c>0$, and knowing that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\,\cos(nx)dx=0$

All I could prove is that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n\,n=0$, and I am not sure it is correct

Comment: $f(x)$ can't be an even function for one. Then using that, I think you can apply the Wierstrass M test. Or maybe see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268758/prove-sin-x-is-uniformly-continuous-on-mathbb-r).

Comment: @Mattos I tried it but the best I got was $M_n=\lvert b_n\,n\rvert$, and I can't prove that $\sum M_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may suppose that $c = 1$ and $a =1$ without lost of generality.  Start with what we know from  $f $ being *of C <sup>2</sup>*.

Let $T(x) = \frac{1}{2}{a_0} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{a_n}\cos (nx) + {b_n}\sin (nx)} \right)}$ be the Fourier series of $f$.  Since  $f'$  is continuous, $ f $ is absolutely continuous and $T(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly to $f(x)$ and the differentiated series is the Fourier series of $ f '$, that is

$S(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( -n{{a_n}\sin (nx) + n{b_n}\cos (nx)} \right)}$

is the Fourier series of $ f '$.  Then we can deduce that $T(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly.  More precisely,

$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {{a_k}} \right|}  < \infty $ and 
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {{b_k}} \right|}  < \infty $ .
We shall prove this first then apply this result to the Fourier series of $ f '$.

Since $ f '$ is continuous and so it is square integrable. Let ${B_n} = - n{a_n}$ and ${A_n} = n{b_n}$.  Then by the Parseval identity,

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {A_n^2 + B_n^2} \right)}  < \infty $.

Therefore,

$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left| {\frac{{{B_k}}}{k}} \right|}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{{B_k^2}}{{{k^2}}}} }  \le {\left\{ {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {B_k^2} } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{k^2}}}} } \right)} \right\}^{1/2}} \le {\left\{ {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {B_k^2} } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{k^2}}}} } \right)} \right\}^{1/2}} < \infty $ .

Hence

$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {{a_k}} \right|}  < \infty $ .
Similarly we can deduce that $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {{b_k}} \right|}  < \infty $ .

Now we have $f'$ is differentiable and that $f''$ is continuous. By what we just show

$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {k{a_k}} \right|}  < \infty $ and 
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {k{b_k}} \right|}  < \infty $ .

Now apply Weierstrass M-test, we have $g(t)$ converges absolutely and uniformly.